# Stripe API Batch Transfers

Tags: transactions, stripe-payments, idempotent

I'd like to run a list of transfers (from Account to Account) in a transactional way, meaning not one by one but with semantics "either all or none."

Currently, I see that I should iterate and run them one by one, therefore in my List of transfers, there could be partial errors / partial successes. This is fine and I'm ready to handle this case, but it will be a lot more code than just telling stripe, "Run all or none".

Is there any best practice for doing this?

Comment: Stripe doesn't have any such concept as a batch API or action like that, so the only real option is to make multiple individual API calls as you mention.